# how to add plist file to iPhone/iPod device in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, plist, device, addition

I am running the following code in xcode.When I run it in simulator there is content inside offlineData but upon running on device the content is nil.

```
NSString *offlinePlistDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *offlineFilePath = nil;
offlineFilePath = [offlinePlistDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"offline.plist"]; 
NSData *offlineData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:offlineFilePath];
```

I have the offline.plist file inside the documents folder inside Library......

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: first remove your install app from your device then rebuild

Comment: still the same result friend..!!..I think when run on device, it does not get the plist in the documents folder.No idea how to have it inside the device. Please help.

Answer (score -1):

Try Out with the below code

```
#define USER_DATA_PLIST_PATH    [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"offline.plist"]
#define USER_DATA_PLIST [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:USER_DATA_PLIST_PATH]

NSMutableDictionary *d = USER_DATA_PLIST;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this help...but do I necessarily have to have dictionary..??..can't I use NSData. It is so because I am using the following code where I have to pass an NSData, since it contains a propertyListFromData.

[NSPropertyListSerialization 
                                         propertyListFromData:USER_DATA_PLIST 
                                         mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves 
                                         format:&format errorDescription:&errorDesc]]

Comment: i am just given example you can use according your data type